# 'Better comment' extension not working on C/C++ files in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments

I just discovered that my 'better comment' extension stopped working after updating the visual studio code IDE.

[image]

It could not highlight comments in C/C++ files, but worked perfectly in other languages:

[image]

Here is the list of extensions I installed:

- C/C++ Extension Pack

  - C/C++
  - CMake
  - C/C++ Themes
- Doxygen Documentation Generator

I tried reinstalling the extension, but it did not work.

I'm wondering if anyone else got the same issue as me.

Answer (score 0):

Was running into this same problem on C files and it seems to be an issue with a JSON parser for VS Code as explained by https://github.com/aaron-bond/better-comments/issues/437#issuecomment-1274590408

> Investigation revealed that the problem was in the file Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\cpp\language-configuration.json which was missing a comma at the end of line 16

So just adding back in that comma fixed it for me